# Which one is correct "Where I was or Where was I"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am little bit confuse to use Where I was or Where was I.

For Example I use -

> My brother wanted to know where was I?

Please help

Comment: Have you considered posting questions as basic as these to our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)?   Your question is really too basic for the current site unless you are expecting a complex and scholarly response.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.